# advancedBy in Swift 3. Code conversion

Tags: swift, syntax, migration

i cant make the code to work. Im reading the AppCoda tutorial and this code is written in swift 2.
It should make a dictorionary grouped with first letters from an array

```
    func createAnimalDict() {
    for animal in animals {
        // Get the first letter of the animal name and build the dictionary
        let animalKey =
animal.substringToIndex(animal.startIndex.advancedBy(1))
        if var animalValues = animalsDict[animalKey] {
            animalValues.append(animal)
            animalsDict[animalKey] = animalValues
        } else {
            animalsDict[animalKey] = [animal]
} }
    // Get the section titles from the dictionary's keys and sort them in
ascending order
    animalSectionTitles = [String](animalsDict.keys)
    animalSectionTitles = animalSectionTitles.sort({ $0 < $1 })
}
```

it should give me an dictonary like

```
animalsDict["B"] = ["Bear", "Black Swan", "Buffalo"]
animalsDict["C"] = ["Camel"]
```

but i cant make this code to work. I tried to converting it myself but it doesnt work (im a beginner)

```
func createAnimalDict() {
    for animal in animals {
        // Get the first letter of the animal name and build the dictionary
        let animalKey = animal.substring(to: animal.index(animal.startIndex, offsetBy: 1))
        if var animalValues = animalsDict[animalKey] {
            animalValues.append(animal)
            animalsDict[animalKey] = animalValues
        } else {
            animalsDict[animalKey] = [animal]
        } }
    // Get the section titles from the dictionary's keys and sort them in ascending order
    animalSectionTitles = [String](animalsDict.keys)
    animalSectionTitles = animalSectionTitles.sorted(by: { $0 < $1 })
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by " it doesnt work" ? Do you get an error ?

Comment: when i try to access the dictonary it says its empty, so i dont know whats to problem